# Round sword hilt

Tags: modeling

Please give me some advise. How to make the hilt of the sword like on the picture (Hole doesn't matter)? For a long time trying to figure out how to do it, but nothing happens. Help :(
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could begin with a 2D mesh with your picture as background image. Try to follow the slopes and anticipate a topology that will allow you to add edge loops along the angles. Then drag up in 3D, bring some corrections with knife or merge, and add the edge loops.

[image]

Comment: Wow. That's really awesome. I will try. Thank you very much